# I have javascript to get new time and date

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code to get new time. But when i reload the page the time doesn't change instead it says `1/10/2014 10:57`, how can i add a function for the time and date to detect and change

Below is the code I tried but its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    // using current UTC time from server as ref, display local time in div id="now"
    var now = new Date();
    now.setTime(1389322677492);
    var nowstr = "" 
        + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "/"
        + now.getDate() + "/"
        + ((now.getYear() < 1000) ? now.getYear() + 1900 : now.getYear()) + " "
        + now.getHours() + ":"
        + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + now.getMinutes() : now.getMinutes());
    var el = document.getElementById("now");
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nowstr));
  })();
</script>
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are explicitly setting it to `1389322677492` everytime. All you need to do is remove the line:

```
now.setTime(1389322677492);
```